# Long dependency of phrases in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, repetition

I wrote this sentences:

> In the Web accessibility tools, speech rendering of **the main content [of a web page]** can provide better access to **a web page** for the visually impaired users.
>   Extracting and presenting **the main block [of the page]** can also make browsing **the page** easier over constrained devices like mobile phones
>
> In particular, we employ **the textual delimiters and semantic cues [within a web page]**  to locate the data of interest **within a web page**. (However, in this last sentence I prefer to keep it in its first place).

To avoid repeating some words, I relocated and left out the second part of possessive constructions [in the brackets] yet kept the "the" before the first part.

Are my sentences correct and convey the meaning I want? Could it be a technique to avoid repeating some phrases and make more fluent sentences?

Comment: I think you have the right idea. Also implied information (such as "a web page" in the first example) might be left out if it is understood by the reader. For example "In the Web accessibility tools, speech rendering of the main content can provide better access for (the) visually impaired users."

Comment: "for visually impaired users"

Comment: Other than the first time "web page" appears, I would leave out the word "web" and just say "page". In context it is clear that you are talking about web pages; I think it flows better without repeating "web" everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This domain already has a few terms of trade which could make your paragraph more succinct.

Our web-accessibility tools offer several aids and conveniences.
**Text-to-speech** provides visually impaired users with better access to page content.  **Text-extraction** facilitates reading on constrained devices such as mobile phones.

We employ text delimiters as well as semantic cues to identify content-of-interest on the page.

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't say about my idea about leaving out parts of the phrases and bringing them ahead in the sentence.

Comment: Because IMO you need to focus not on "flow" and "technique" but on clarity and brevity.

Comment: Thank you, but by "In Web accessibility tools", I don't mean "Our web-ac..." I mean what is common in such tools. Maybe I should leave out "the"

Comment: Your use of "the" suggests that you're referring to specific tools (i.e. your tools) and this idea is further reinforced by the phrase "in particular, *we* employ..."  So, if you're referring to tools in general, yes, omit the article.  Web-accessibility tools...  Also, that prepositional phrase is not clear "In web-accessibility tools". You mean to say something like "With web-accessibility tools, the goal is to aid the reader or make things more convenient.  For example, with text-to-speech..."

Comment: the subject is "extracting the main block" and I count its applications. like "*in X, it is used for Y, in Z it is used for W....*" Does it convey that?

Comment: Maybe I just should say "In Web Accessibility, ...."

Comment: You are using the pronoun "In" there in a strange way, IMO.

Comment: for example in this document https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process, you see sentences started with  in mathematics, in physics. why not?

Comment: Because there, the noun in the prepositional-phrase is an established *domain* (e.g. In mathematics). To use "in" with "web-accessibility" is to raise "web accessibility" to the level of a domain. If that is what you intended to say, then you should not have written "in *the* web-accessibility tools", because "the" refers to *specific* instances of things, not to domains.  It is not clear to me from the minimal context what you are trying to say.